# Reading CA Cert Private Key to Sign Certificate

Tags: java, security, ssl, x509certificate

I have a requirement as below:

1. Create a self signed (say CA cert) and save the cert and private key
   to files
2. Load the CA Cert (Created in Step 1) and its private key
3. Create a end
   certificate which is signed using CA Cert and Private Key loaded in
   Step 2

My Private Key is Stored to a file as below:

```
public static void writePrivateKey(PrivateKey privateKey, OutputStream os) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8EncodedKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(
            privateKey.getEncoded());
    bos.write(pkcs8EncodedKeySpec.getEncoded());
    bos.close();
  }
```

My private Key is loaded back as below:

```
 public PrivateKey loadPrivatekey(InputStream privateKeyInputStream)
          throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException
  {
    return KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithamForCreatingAndLoadingKeys)
            .generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(IOUtils.toByteArray(privateKeyInputStream)));
  }
```

I have my algorithm defined as RSA

```
 private String algorithamForCreatingAndLoadingKeys = "RSA";
```

Iam signing my certificate as below:

```
 private static X509CertImpl buildAndSignCert(X509CertInfo certInfo, PrivateKey privateKey)
          throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException,
          NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException, IOException
  {
    X509CertImpl cert = new X509CertImpl(certInfo);
    String algorithm = "SHA1withRSA";
    // Sign the cert to identify the algorithm that's used.
    cert.sign(privateKey, algorithm);
    // Update the algorith, and resign.
    certInfo.set(CertificateAlgorithmId.NAME + "." + CertificateAlgorithmId.ALGORITHM,
            cert.get(X509CertImpl.SIG_ALG));
    X509CertImpl newCert = new X509CertImpl(certInfo);
    newCert.sign(privateKey, algorithm);
    return newCert;
  }
```

Problem: If i create the CA cert and end certificate **without saving and loading the key file** I was able to validate the end certificate fine:

> C:\Workspace.....\src\main\resources>openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem end.pem
>
> end.pem: OK

But If i save and load the key files and verify, I get below error, which clearly says that my end certificate is not signed correct with my ca cert

> C:\Workspace.....\src\main\resources>openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem
>   end.pem
>
> end.pem: C = AU, L = ABC, CN = XYZ
>
> error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate

So, Iam coming to the conclusion that my saving of private key and loading it is buggered.

Can any one pleas help what Iam doing wrong in saving and reading private keys ?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, I tried to create a CA cert and private key outside Java word using OpenSSL and load the file to Sign the end cert and it went valid. So, may be saving the file has the issue ?

Comment: To narrow down the issue further, the key you saved is not the same as the key you read back in, correct? Everything else is irrelevant.

Comment: I wish that could be it. But unfortunately, Iam reading back the same key that I saved.

Comment: You've checked that? It is bitwise identical before and after? If so, you should include that fact, and the evidence, in your question.

Comment: Yes.. I have checked the file Iam creating and reading as below:

Saving Public Key to C:\Workspace\...\src\main\resources/public.key
Saving Private Key to C:\Workspace\...\src\main\resources/private.key
Reading Public Key C:\Workspace\...\src\main\resources/public.key
Reading Private Key C:\Workspace\...\src\main\resources/private.key



How ever I have not did bit wise comaprison

Comment: Not 'as below ' thanks. **In your question.** But when you're asked whether it is bitwise identical, that is the one thing you need to actually answer. Not whether you've written and read files. That proves exactly nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97574/discussion-between-shiv-and-ejp).

Comment: Just answer the questions you are asked here, and in your question, as requested.

Comment: Iam not sure how I can do that comparison.. when I print the file content on console I see some ASCII characters where as in my file I see like 'aced 0005 7372 0014 6a61 7661 2e6d 6174
682e 4269 6749 .....'

Comment: You can't compare the content of two byte arrays? Really?

Comment: Arrays.equals(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/ca-private.key"))),
                    caPrivatekey.getEncoded())

Yes they are equal.. above statemenet gave me true.

Comment: Please ignore the key name in above statement.. I changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the **code that I have posted above is correct and accurate to create and read a private key file**.

I have spotted the problem to be with loading the Created CA Cert itself (not the private key), some how when we generate X509 Certificate as below:

```
CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate loadedCaCert = (X509Certificate) f
            .generateCertificate(CertificateGenerator.class.getResourceAsStream("/ca.pem"));
```

the serial number that it is producing out of X509Certificate generated above is not the same as the one I passed when creating CA certtificate (Which is another issue but not realted to thsi thread anyways) and as we pass this serial number to subscriber certificate to identify its parent CA for certificate linking its failing.

Thank You

Comment: In that case your statement that the problem only exists when saving and loading the key file wasn't correct.

Comment: Yes.. I was thinking that some how my key file was not being read right or saved right and went in that direction and posted this in that view. Now I ended up finding that what ever i posted above is absolutely correct. Thanks for your time and will appreciate if you leave me any leads on why the serial number is changing every time I load it. Thank You

Comment: Are you putting your project in a jar? If so, and you then replace (or alter) the *file* `...\ca.pem`, `Class.getResource*` will get the data in the jar, NOT the data in the file.

Comment: Nah my project is not in a separate jar and my code in my question is perfectly fine. Thank You.